# How to set CFBundleShortVersionString in an Xcode Cloud Workflow

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, build-automation

I am finding it difficult to get help with Xcode Cloud Workflows. We use Xcode Cloud to build and deploy to App Store Connect. Building for TestFlight is simple because Xcode Cloud automatically updates the build number.

When trying to make a publicly deployable build using an Xcode Cloud Workflow I get I get the error "Invalid Pre-Release Train" during the Archive step. The details of the error are "The train version '5.0.26' is closed for new build submissions. " This means manual intervention to increment the `CFBundleShortVersionString` before starting a build is required which defeats the automatic part of build "automation."

In order to make a build deployable to the public you must have a unique `CFBundleShortVersionString`. I am setting `CFBundleShortVersionString` in my targets info.plist like so

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>       <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION).$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
```

This works great and gives me a `CFBundleShortVersionString` that looks something like 5.0.27 but requires I manually increment `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` in my project.pbxproj before trying to do the build. Again that is not automation.

If I could somehow set `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` to CI_BUILD_NUMBER that would ensure my `CFBundleShortVersionString` would always be unique eliminating manual intervention. In the workflow Environment Variables I tried setting `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` to $(CI_BUILD_NUMBER) but that did not seem to affect my build at all. The timing may be off or maybe environment variables are not considered when the build system evaluates project.pbxproj.

Any help getting my solution to work or any other solution that would work with Xcode Cloud would be greatly appreciated!

(I can't say cloud cloud cloud enough because most of the solutions out there are Xcode running on a local or build machine and I need a solution for Xcode cloud)